# pandas count total of last 7 days but varying dates across groupby

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have this dataframe:

```
    date        state   cases flag
0   2020-03-13  Alabama 6     0
1   2020-03-14  Alabama 12    0
2   2020-03-15  Alabama 23    0
3   2020-03-16  Alabama 29    1
4   2020-03-17  Alabama 39    0
```

I want to count # of cases for the past 7 days from the date where the flag column is = 1. I've tried some variations on other answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914458/pandas-count-values-for-last-7-days-from-each-date) with no luck. I have data for multiple states and need to groupby state.

Output should look like:

```
state     count
Alabama   70
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried, so that users can comment on what the issue is and provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a rolling-sum over 7 days (assuming we have data for all states for all days):

```
res_df = df[['state', 'cases']].groupby('state')['cases'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(7, 1).sum().iloc[-1])
print(res_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to tell from the question as it is quite unclear but maybe try:

`df.groupby('State').rolling(7).count()`

Comment: This might fail if there are non-numeric columns in the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that *flag* column contains *1* in only one row (in each state).

So the proper algorithm, for the current *state*, is:

- find *date* where *flag == 1* (flag date),
- find the date 7 days earlier (start date),
- get rows between these dates and sum *cases* column.

To generate your expected result define the following function:

```
def sumCases(grp):
    dFlag = grp[grp.flag == 1].iloc[0,0]
    dStart = dFlag - pd.Timedelta('7d')
    return grp[grp.date.between(dStart, dFlag)].cases.sum()
```

Then apply it:

```
result = df.groupby('state').apply(sumCases)
```

But if any state can have **multiple** rows with *flag == 1*,
another approach is needed.

Define the summing fuction as:

```
def sumCases2(grp):
    flagDate = grp[grp.flag == 1].date
    ind = [ pd.date_range(dd - pd.Timedelta('7d'), dd).to_series() for dd in flagDate ]
    return grp[grp.date.isin(pd.concat(ind).unique())].cases.sum()
```

Then apply it:

```
result = df.groupby('state').apply(sumCases2)
```